# Why does std::iswalpha return false for some French characters in C++?

Tags: c++, non-ascii-characters

I am using `std::iswalpha` to check if a non-ASCII character (French character) is alphabetic. However, I have found that it returns `false` for `é` character. I have set my locale to `fr_FR.UTF-8` in my code. Can you help me understand why this is happening and how I can correctly determine whether a French character is alphabetic using C++?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cwctype>

int main() {
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.UTF-8");
    wchar_t ch = L'é';
    bool is_alpha = std::iswalpha(ch);
    std::cout << is_alpha << std::endl; // print 0
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because installing the locale fails, but you don't check that.

Running this in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/rdW9Pvq3x) prints `locale: No such file or directory` while running it on my local computer where I have the `fr_FR.UTF-8` locale installed succeeds and prints `1`:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cwctype>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    if (std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.UTF-8") == nullptr) {
        std::perror("locale");
    } else {
        wint_t ch = L'é';
        bool is_alpha = std::iswalpha(ch);
        std::cout << is_alpha << std::endl;  // print 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there an alternative method to check if a non-ASCII character is alphabetic in C++, without relying on a specific locale to be pre-installed? I plan to use this code in an Android device with the NDK, and I am unsure how to require a specific locale on that device.

Comment: @Abdo21 Android has ICU library. You can use it.